# String functions in JQuery

Tags: jquery, string, methods

I have another little question regarding the Jquery basics.
I've tried doing a String method on a variable I made, but it told me that I couldn't use that method.

Here's what I did:

```
var tekst="";

$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('#vertaalnaar').bind('click', VertaalNaar);
    }
);

function VertaalNaar() {                
tekst = prompt("Geef je boodschap in: ","Defaultvalue");

tekst = tekst.toUpper();        
tekst.replace(A,J);
}
```

And this is the error I got:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object Defaultvalue has no method 'toUpper'
>   (19:38:11:501 | error, javascript)
>       at VertaalNaar (public_html/extra.html:28:23)
>       at b.event.dispatch (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3:28337)
>       at v.handle (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3:25042)

I don't know how I have to make Jquery use the var type object as a String object.
I've found quite alot of information on how to do this in Javascript, but I can't seem to find information about Jquery.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Name of the method is `.toUpperCase()`.

Comment: Also, `A` and `J` aren't variables as far as I can see, and it's Javascript in this case, not jQuery, and you need to [read MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript) more.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that I didn't place my letters between quotes after the replace method and saw your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method called `toUpper` in JavaScript (*no such function in jQuery either*) (*its `toUpperCase()`*)

```
tekst = tekst.toUpperCase();
```

Here is documentation from MDN: [`.toUpperCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)